# Error saving LocalDateTime in TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, sql-timestamp

I am using ***Java 8*** and ***Hibernate 5.2.9***
I have an object which contains variable end

```
@Column(name = "end", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime end;
```

and in database the field is defined as

```
`end`        TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL
```

So when I try to do

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(object);
```

I get

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x0E\x05\x00\x00\x07\xE1\x08\x0F\x13\x1E\x13\x1C1h@' for column 'end' at row 1
```

Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here since I assumed that java 8 and hibernate 5.2.9 know what `LocalDateTime` is. I would appreciate any help since I am stuck.

Comment: [this](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/) example explains about java 8 support with hibernate 5 for `LocalDateTime`.It may be helpful.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu that article states that what I have should work without any problems. Yet it seems somehow it doesn't  and I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using two different date type.

`TIMESTAMP` -: '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC

`LocalDateTime` -: 2017-08-16T05:22:23.832`

use one `Date` formate

Comment: How do I go about doing so? LocalDateTime is a native Java Object

Comment: what is the format you want to save. `2017-08-16T05:22:23.832` this one   or  `2017-08-15 03:14:07`  this one or any other formate

Comment: use this annotation `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: that gives me `@Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property`

Comment: `import javax.persistence.Temporal` 

 `import javax.persistence.TemporalType`



    @Column(name = "end", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
     private Date end;

Comment: yes I had that. It still says same error. Temporal seems to be something to not be used with LocalDateTime

Comment: now do't use `LocalDateTime ` date formate use only `Date` ,

`private Date end`

Comment: That would be a bit too backwards. LocalDateTime was introduced to java 8 along with other joda time objects because they are superior in every way compared to Date or Calendar. This is just one hiccup I am trying to solve that's all.

Comment: I do't know much more details about java8.  

         `@Type(type = "timestamp")`
          `private LocalDateTime end;` In my case this is work